# Generating 3rd harmonic injection

Tags: stm32, power-electronics, pwm, inverter

I'm designing an inverter and I see this 3rd harmonic injection part a lot. My question is: how do I generate a 3rd harmonic?

What I understood is that I am supposed to generate a calculated 3rd harmonic table along with the sine reference table, since I'm using carrier-based PWM generation. If this is the case, then how do I generate one? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: *I'm using carrier-based PWM generation.* Meaning, the PWM doesn't come from an MCU or something like that?

Comment: yes PWM is being generated from the MCU , not hardware based.

Comment: As I understand from reading some articles you modify the sinus reference table in a way that it contains the sum of scaled up original sinus and a fraction (1/6) of the third harmonic.

Comment: yes exactly , I generate the Table using a Software that gives me the exact x steps in the 180 degree region. So that means If  I generate 1/6 of the reference sine wave using the same software , sum them both up which for now I dont know then  I should get my 3rd harmonic cancelled  ?

Answer (score 2):

Although new to me, my understanding is injecting 3rd harmonic into 3 phase delta improves the DC utilization of the generation while the 3rd harmonics cancel Line to Neutral.  The same approach may also be used in Space-Vector modulation which is normally implemented by a DSP.  They seem to use 1/6 1f peak amplitudes although my casual inspection shows no ripple with 100% 1f and 12% 3f.
[image]

I'm not sure if [these academic level reports](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/236645847_Novel_Third_Harmonic_Current_Injection_Technique_for_Harmonic_Reduction_of_Controlled_Converters/figures) are much help, they do compare various methods of 3rd harmonic control.  In order to implement a cost reduction in software, you need a solid design in hardware which I have yet to see beyond research papers.

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/353157639_Scalar_and_Vector_Controlled_Infinite_Level_Inverter_ILI_Topology_Fed_Open-Ended_Three-Phase_Induction_Motor/figures?lo=1

[image]

[image]

### Other

I don't see any reference link in your question, but a square wave inverter automatically injects the 3f @ -9.5dB from 1f so to nullify that you need to add -9.5 dB with the opposite phase.

Generally speaking "carrier-based PWM" try to simulate a sine wave using a string batteries in order to switch at cosine intervals to reduce the harmonic losses in transformers.  With filtering, this might be called a "sine inverter".

The novel improvements in this design have balanced the switching rate of harmonic and subharmonic switches to compensate for the phase shift and power factor of the load.  You may have read similar but different methods.

> "A six-level back-to-back diode-clamped converter proto-type has established that these novel carrier-based switching
> strategies can be used to enable better switch utilization."

e.g. [image]  [link](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.453.1103&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

(p.s. I see references to previous designs by my former Prof in the '70s R.W. Menzies.)

Comment: Thankyou , @Tony Stewart EE75 , The reason I haven't given any reference is because most articles don't explain a laymen approach to practically solving the problem , instead a heavy math approach is given , I asked this question for the sole purpose of implementing it in software !

Comment: the hardware that you have illustrated does reduce harmonics and reduced switching losses , but at the cost of increased switches which is not economically viable in my application !

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I could create with Multism  , Carrier Based Pwm Generation with 3rd Harmonic Injection, Although Im stilled confused as whether Ive inserted the right value for the 3rd harmonic wave.

The Circuit  Design :

[image]

The Waves Generated :

[image]